# In PHP, why is preg_match more desirable vs ctype functions?

Tags: php, preg-match

I've noticed that in a lot of answers, the preg_match answer is selected as "the" answer far more often than the ctype_* answers are. Is there some kind of superiority to one over the other, objectively, or is it merely a matter of preference? The php manual doesn't seem to shed any light on it that I can see. And since I wouldn't actually understand much by getting my hands down into the brains of PHP, I'm really just interested to know if there's some kind of performance difference or other objective measurement.

Comment: To do what, exactly?

Comment: The `preg_match` can do more than a `ctype` function. Depending on what you are going to be doing either could work. Checking for an alphanumerical string with at least one number wont be possible with a `ctype`.

Comment: Historic availability: regex functions have pretty much always been there.

Comment: Maybe an answer that expresses this could be forthcoming?